# Between clause from recordset

Tags: sql, sql-server

This may be weird, but I would like to somehow combine BETWEEN clause with the table, like in the following example.

Say we have two tables:

```
Tbl1
╔════════╦════════╗
║ Value1 ║ Value2 ║
╠════════╬════════╣
║      1 ║      3 ║
║      5 ║      8 ║
╚════════╩════════╝

Tbl2
╔═══════╦══════╗
║ Value ║ Stat ║
╠═══════╬══════╣
║     1 ║    5 ║
║     2 ║    0 ║
║     3 ║    8 ║
║     5 ║    1 ║
║     7 ║    2 ║
║    10 ║    0 ║
║    11 ║    5 ║
║    14 ║    7 ║
╚═══════╩══════╝
```

Tbl1 sets the rule for intervals, and Tbl2 sets instances that fall between intervals.
Here's how it goes:

- first interval is 1 to 3, so take all Tbl2 records where Value is between 1 and 3 and sum up Stat
- first interval is 5 to 8, so take all Tbl2 records where Value is between 5 and 8 and sum up Stat

I can do it using multiple selects like this:

```
SELECT sum(Stat) FROM Tbl2 WHERE [Value] BETWEEN 1 AND 3
SELECT sum(Stat) FROM Tbl2 WHERE [Value] BETWEEN 5 AND 8
```

Is there a way to sum up everything in just one select?
I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, if that makes a difference for you.

Using cursor is out of the question because there's a **LOT** of recors and rules in these two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Use `Join on Between Condition`

```
SELECT  b.value1, b.value2, sum(a.Stat) 
FROM   table2 a
       JOIN table1 b
         ON a.value BETWEEN b.value1 AND b.value2 
 GROUP BY b.value1, b.value2
```

Comment: That works, of course. Can't believe my SQL skills become so rusty after few months of avoiding ye olde hardcore db work.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT tbl1.value1, tbl1.value2, sum(tbl2.Stat) 
FROM Tbl1
JOIN Tbl2 ON tbl2.Value BETWEEN tbl1.value1 AND tbl1.value2
GROUP BY tbl1.value1, tbl1.value2
```